# WP 3.8 Admin dashboard unreachable after language change in config

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, dashboard

After following the instructions on the Dutch wordpress.org to switch the site over to Dutch instead of English the admin panel becomes unreachable, though the site still functions.

Instructions are:

- download latest WP version (3.8, being the same as the English one that was on there)
- overwrite files on the server
- go to wp-config.php and change `define('WPLANG', '');` to `define('WPLANG', 'nl_NL');`

Done all that, site is switched to Dutch, including the plugins/widgets/themeparts that support it, so that's all good. But the admin panel is now unreachable when the site is set to Dutch. When deleting the `nl_NL` for a switch back to English it works like nothings happened.

Any idea on how to fix it? Havent been able to find an answer on SO, WP forums, WP NL forums...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it by deleting everything from the server after backing up wp-config, the theme, uploaded data and some other stuff (analytics and such). Then copied the Dutch version to the server, updated the wp-config (with `define('WPLANG', 'nl_NL');`) and uploaded that plus all the other stuff as well.

That fixed it, but shouldn't be the way to do things according to the [WP site](http://nl.wordpress.org).

Recommendation to others wishing to switch langauge is to take this into consideration, for if the event might occur. Also, don't make any edits to the DB during this operation and it should continue to function as if nothings changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your nl_NL.php language file in /wp-content/languages/?

Check if it has the 'admin' word defined there as in the english language file, if not, write it there.

I hopes this will solve the problem.

Comment: There is no nl_NL.php in /languages/ or in /languages/themes/. All of the files are *.mo or *.po. There are 2 admin files: admin-nl_NL.mo & .po. Should something be edited in either/both of these?